# pandas.HDFStore.append_to_multiple with pandas.MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I write a DataFrame to two tables using `pandas.HDFStore.append_to_multiple` and then read it back with `pandas.HDFStore.select_as_multiple`, but I get a DataFrame with extra rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                       b=[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],
                       c=[6,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,6,7],
                       d=np.random.rand(10),
                       e=np.random.rand(10)))
df = df.set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
df
>>>
            d           e
a   b   c       
1   4   6   0.576224    0.285766
        7   0.642458    0.098230
        6   0.579436    0.017601
        7   0.740945    0.769283
        6   0.758087    0.057052
2   4   7   0.092393    0.570647
        6   0.960140    0.094415
        7   0.940927    0.071686
        6   0.289833    0.003229
        7   0.274301    0.859293

store.append_to_multiple({'idx':['d'], 'data':None}, df, 
                         selector='idx', dropna=True, index=True)
```

Then I read it back in:

```
df2 = store.select_as_multiple(['idx' , 'data'])
df2
>>>
            d           e
a   b   c       
1   4   6   0.325709    0.989198
        6   0.498586    0.857124
        6   0.348262    0.720234
        6   0.325709    0.989198
        6   0.498586    0.857124
        6   0.348262    0.720234
        6   0.325709    0.989198
        6   0.498586    0.857124
        6   0.348262    0.720234
        7   0.244739    0.327261
        7   0.640157    0.654922
        7   0.244739    0.327261
        7   0.640157    0.654922
2   4   6   0.761300    0.288723
        6   0.157579    0.404413
        6   0.761300    0.288723
        6   0.157579    0.404413
        7   0.491842    0.713137
        7   0.916732    0.610775
        7   0.002731    0.119276
        7   0.491842    0.713137
        7   0.916732    0.610775
        7   0.002731    0.119276
        7   0.491842    0.713137
        7   0.916732    0.610775
        7   0.002731    0.119276
```

I expect `df2` to equal `df` but it has extra rows. Stepping through the debugger, I see the following line in pytables.py:

```
992:           value = value.ix[valid_index]
```

This is where the DataFrame is reindexed improperly. This seems to be due to the fact the original DataFrame's index has duplicates, but that is the reality of my data. Does this function require the DataFrame to not have duplicate index values? Is there an easy way I can add another level to the MultiIndex to make the index have no duplicates?

It works properly if I remove `dropna=True`:

```
store.append_to_multiple({'idx':['d'], 'data':None}, df, 
                         selector='idx', index=True)
df2 = store.select_as_multiple(['idx' , 'data'])
df2
>>>
            d           e
a   b   c       
1   4   6   0.217079    0.880129
        6   0.498363    0.668485
        6   0.789133    0.726899
        7   0.395735    0.200052
        7   0.397049    0.634318
2   4   6   0.406110    0.373711
        6   0.634547    0.715953
        7   0.723585    0.144365
        7   0.844752    0.696289
        7   0.508510    0.751932
```

Windows x64 Python 2.7 pandas 0.18.1

Comment: This may well be a bug. I have [filed an issue for it](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13547).